# Why did my variables in python not work

Tags: python, loops, variables, while-loop

I am suppose to create a game where the computer picks a random word and the player has to guess that word. The computer will then tell the player how many letters are in the word. Then the player gets five chances to ask whether a letter is in the word. The computer can only respond with "yes" or "no". Then, the player must guess the word.

Somehow, the program that I wrote below is not accurately giving the player 5 chances to ask the whether the letter is in the word before letting the player guess the word. May I know what went wrong? Thank you!

```
    import random

    WORDS = ("hello", "running", "help", "united")
    word = random.choice(WORDS)

    correct = word
    letters=len(word)

    print "There are", len(word), "letters in the word. You have 5 chances to guess the letter in the word. After which you will be required to guess the word."

    guess_letter = raw_input("Guess a letter in the word.")
    tries = 0

    while guess_letter in word:
    tries +=1
    print "Yes"
    guess_letter = raw_input("Guess another letter in the word.")
    if tries == 4:
      print "Please guess the word."
    answer = raw_input("What is the word?")
    if answer == correct:
      print "That is correct!"
    else:
      print "You lose."

    while guess_letter not in word:
    tries +=1
    print "No"
    guess_letter = raw_input("Guess another letter in the word.")
    if tries == 4:
      print "Please guess the word."
    answer = raw_input("What is the word?")
    if answer == correct:
      print "That is correct!"
    else:
      print "You lose."
```

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: if you only have  5 changes why don't you use a `for loop` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two `while` loops one after the other are not correct logic (the indentation as you report it is also broken but I'm guessing that's just a problem of your copy-and-paste here, not of your code itself, or else you'd be getting syntax errors:-).

Suppose for example that the first time the player picks a `guess_letter` that's **not** in the word: then the first `while` exits immediately **and will never be entered again**!

You need a **single** loop, with its iteration independent of whether `guess_letter` is or isn't in the word -- only what is printed should depend on that check!  A `for` loop may be more readable but you can perfectly well do it with a `while` if you prefer -- but it would be something like:

```
while tries < 5:
    tries += 1
    guess_letter = raw_input('Guess another letter in the word.')
    if guess_letter in word:
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'no'
print 'Please guess the word.'
```

with the initialization before it and the last guess and check after it.

I also see you want to treat the first guess differently (specifically, using a different prompt).  That's probably best achieved by using a variable within the prompt...:

```
tries = 0
art = 'a'
while tries < 5:
    tries += 1
    guess_letter = raw_input('Guess ' + art + ' letter in the word.')
    art = 'another'
    if guess_letter in word:
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'no'
print 'Please guess the word.'
```

Comment: THANK YOU ALEX MARTELLI!

Comment: @G.F.Yu, you're welcome -- please remember to **accept** the answer (clic on the checkmark-shaped outline to its left), as is crucial StackOverflow etiquette!-)

Answer (score 0):

The following works. Its sloppy and I don't like it much but I think your biggest issue could have been indentation. After that I added a while loop to nest your two other while loops.

If you want to change something to clean it up I would suggest one while loop (while tries < 4) and then replace the original while loops with if else statements.

```
import random

WORDS = ("hello", "running", "help", "united")
word = random.choice(WORDS)

correct = word
letters=len(word)

print "There are", len(word), "letters in the word. You have 5 chances to guess the letter in the word. After which you will be required to guess the word."

guess_letter = raw_input("Guess a letter in the word.")

while tries < 4:        
    while guess_letter in word:
        tries +=1
        print "Yes"
        guess_letter = raw_input("Guess another letter in the word.")
        if tries == 4:
            print "Please guess the word."
            answer = raw_input("What is the word?")
            if answer == correct:
                print "That is correct!"
            else:
                print "You lose."
        break
    while guess_letter not in word:
        tries +=1
        print "No"
        guess_letter = raw_input("Guess another letter in the word.")
        if tries == 4:
            print "Please guess the word."
            answer = raw_input("What is the word?")
            if answer == correct:
                print "That is correct!"
            else:
                print "You lose."
        break
```

cleaned up version:

```
import random

WORDS = ("hello", "running", "help", "united")
word = random.choice(WORDS)

correct = word
letters=len(word)
tries = 0

print "There are", len(word), "letters in the word. You have 5 chances to guess the letter in the word. After which you will be required to guess the word."

while tries < 4:
    tries +=1
    guess_letter = raw_input("Guess a letter in the word.")
    if guess_letter in word:
        print "Yes"

    else:
        print "No"

print "Please guess the word."
answer = raw_input("What is the word?")
if answer == correct:
    print "That is correct!"
else:
    print "You lose."
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems too complicated. I advise you to use a `for` loop, which fits to your problem. Here is a lightweight version of your game (tested on Python 3.4):

```
import random

WORDS = ("hello", "running", "help", "united")
word = random.choice(WORDS)

print("There are {} letters in the word.".format(len(word)),
      "You have 5 chances to guess a letter in the word.",
      "After which you will be required to guess the word.")

for _ in range(5):
    guess_letter = input("Guess a letter in the word: ")
    if guess_letter in word:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")

answer = input("Guess the word: ")
if answer == word:
    print("That is correct!")
else:
    print("Game over!")
```

Comment: THANK YOU ALEXANDRE FIGURA!